# Transform data table (gather operation?) which has Month of Year in multiple columns, so that Date is in just 1 column

Tags: python, r, transform, data-cleaning

I am trying to transform a data table. The table is currently stored in Google Sheets. I'd be happy to use any platform or language to make the transformation, whether R, Python, GSheets, Excel, whatever.

The format of the current table is:

| Variable | Apr-19 | May-19 | Jun-19 | Jul-19 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| example string 1 | 10 | 10 | 30 | 10 |
| example string 2 | 20 | 40 | 20 | 20 |
| example string 3 | 50 | 80 | 90 | 60 |

Here is how i would like to transform it:

| Date | Keyword | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-04-01 | example string 1 | 10 |
| 2019-05-01 | example string 1 | 10 |
| 2019-06-01 | example string 1 | 30 |
| 2019-07-01 | example string 1 | 10 |
| 2019-04-01 | example string 2 | 20 |
| 2019-05-01 | example string 2 | 40 |
| 2019-06-01 | example string 2 | 20 |
| 2019-07-01 | example string 2 | 20 |
| 2019-04-01 | example string 3 | 50 |
| 2019-05-01 | example string 3 | 80 |
| 2019-06-01 | example string 3 | 90 |
| 2019-07-01 | example string 3 | 60 |

I have 48 months in total across 48 columns, and 6000 rows of data. I understand this will end up giving me 288,000 rows.

Ideally there would be some sort of formula or multi-step of formulas to automate the transformation in Google Sheets, as the data will eventually be pulled out of the sheet and use in a data visualisation platform, however i'd be happy to export as csv, make the transformation elsewhere, and then import back into GSheets.

Any help much appreciated! Thanks!!

In R i tried using Tidyverse pivot_longer operation but was unsuccessful. I simply couldn't figure out the right way to code it.

In GSheets i tried a multitude of formulas including transpose, arrays, filter, etc.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please show us the code you have tried to use, and provide your data using `dput()`.  This will make your question reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific table you provide you could use pivot_longer like this:

```
data %>%
 pivot_longer(!stars_with("Variable"),
              names_to = "Date",
              names_transform = as.date(),
              values_to = "Volume")
```

Comment: Thank you. This one almost worked, and after some playing around i was able to get the following to work:

`install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(!starts_with("Variable"),
               names_to = "Date",
               names_transform = ~parse_date_time(.x, "m.y"),
               values_to = "Volume")`